# Primefaces: Table sorting and row editing don't work together

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I created a simple primefaces 4.0 table with supports row editing and column sorting. I created two entries and sorted them descending. Now when I change the value of one row with the row editor, after saving the row get overwritten by the data from other row! When I reload the table, everything is OK again.

This are all the steps:

1. Create a simple project with Spring ROO (only one entity with three string fields)
2. Set up primefaces to version 4.0 in pom.xml and changed the source code to primefaces 4.0.
3. Added row editing and column sorting to the table.
4. Started server and entered first entry with all values "1" and second one with all values "2".
5. Sorting any column descending (result: "2" is on top, "1" is on bottom)
6. Edit any value with RowEditor and save.
7. Now the values of edited row are overwritten with values from other row in the view.

This is my jsf code:

```
    <p:dataTable editable="true" id="list" value="#{customerBean.allCustomers}" var="customer" rendered="#{customerBean.dataVisible}" resizableColumns="false" paginator="true" paginatorTemplate=" {CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,25,50" rows="10">
      <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{customerBean.onRowEdit}" update=":growlForm:growl" />
      <p:columns value="#{customerBean.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex"
                 sortBy="#{customer[column]}">
        <f:facet name="header">
          <h:outputText value="#{applicationBean.getColumnName(column)}" />
        </f:facet>
           <p:cellEditor>  
               <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{customer[column]}" /></f:facet>  
               <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="#{customer[column]}Input" value="#{customer[column]}" style="width:96%"/></f:facet>  
           </p:cellEditor> 
      </p:columns>
      <p:column style="width:6%">  
        <p:rowEditor />  
      </p:column>
```

And this the server code:

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    this.setCustomer((Customer) event.getObject());
    this.persist();
}
```

Is it a bug of Roo, of Primefaces, of JSF or of JQuery???
Any hints or workaround? What would be the simplest way to refresh the table after row editing without loosing the current sorting and pagination?

Thanks !!!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

In primefaces 4.0 your `sortBy` should be like this `sortBy="#{column}"` instead of

```
`#{customer[column]}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your customerBean must be ViewScoped or if you have sessionScoped than you need to do like in my example:

```
 <p:dataTable id="settingsTbl" value="#{settingsBean.settingsList}" var="item" editable="true">
```

.....

```
 public List<Settings> getSettingsList() {  
    if(settingsList==null){
        settingsList = settingsFacade.findAll();
    }
    return settingsList;
}
```